# How do I update dependency packages in a project without breaking the dependency tree on install?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies

I recently created a basic Typescript/React npm package for internal use at the company I'm working for, and since it was my first time building one, I used a tool called `create-react-library` (found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library)) to help streamline the process. The library made it quite easy to develop and publish my package, but the problem is that it hasn't been updated recently and thus several of the dependencies are out of date, including the version of React which the rest of our codebase is running on. I can successfully install the package in the main project if I use the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag on `npm install`, but that doesn't seem like an ideal solution. What's the best way to update the dependencies of my package without breaking the dependency tree? I tried going through my `package.json`, manually updating the version numbers to the latest, then deleted `node_modules` and re-ran `npm install`, but I got several dependency tree conflicts and the install failed. What's the best approach here?

Comment: I, too, would like to know. 

I learned the hard way that using abandonware to make a component library was in hindsight not my brightest moment. Ended up starting from scratch with good old create-react-app and using the babel CLI to compile the output to a /dist folder. If that works for your use case, good luck! Otherwise, let's hope the library gods have some advice for us. 

Comment: @Summer I ended up going back into my `package.json` and manually updating only the React versions and nothing else, since the package I made is pretty lightweight and really only relies on that. The installs for both the dev code and the published npm pack both now work, albeit with some deprecation warnings. I'm thinking rewriting the package myself might just be the safest method though as the code I've written isn't too complex. Do you know of any good tutorials for the babel CLI method you used? I probably would have written this from scratch to begin with if I had found a decent one.

Comment: I stumbled upon [this one](https://fathomtech.io/blog/create-a-react-component-library-using-create-react-app/), but unless your library only has components, it won't work if you follow it exactly. The gist of it is near the bottom. Make sure to compile your `src/` directory, and not just `src/components`, and to export your stuff from index.ts. Also use relative import paths, otherwise babel gets confuzzled.

Comment: @Summer Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just set exact versions or ~, but no ^